# Axios: combining data request from interceptors and from component before POST

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, interceptor

I have this function action

```
export function unlinkAccount(id) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    const data = {
      id: id
    };
    return userApi
      .post('/user/account/unlink', data)
      .then(res => console.log('SUCCESS: unlinkAccount -> ', res))
      .catch(err => console.log('ERROR: unlinkAccount -> ', err));
  };
}
```

but I also intercept the request as per following

```
userApi.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    const jwtToken = await refreshToken();
    if (jwtToken) {
      config.data = { accessToken: jwtToken };
    }
    return config;
  },
  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

this will make a POST to `userApi` using the data from the interceptor instead of the `unlinkAccount` function. Is there a way to combine both data or pass as a 'props' to the `unlinkAccount` function as I need to pass data as per the following format:

```
const data = {
   id: id,
   accessToken: jwtToken
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the output of config.data in the interceptor? If config.data is the data from unlinkAccount function, instead of reassigning to interceptor's data (jwtToken), you can merge it with the interceptor data.

Comment: @WeiSengTan ya you're right thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And yeah just figure out the solution, I just change the config.data in interceptor request to

```
if (jwtToken) {
      config.data = { accessToken: jwtToken, ...config.data };
    }
```

so it'll took data from component and combine in intercept data before making a POST.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in the past:

Passing jwtToken everytime you call the api is not a good way, I think.
If you use the following one, you just need to

```
const data = {
      id: id
    };
    return userApi
      .post('/user/account/unlink', data)
```

Also, you don't need to call refreshToken everytime.

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { store } from '../index';
import { updateAuth } from '../redux/actions/auth';
import { apiURL } from '../config';

axios.defaults.baseURL = apiURL;

// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const { tokenType, accessToken, loggedIn } = store.getState().auth;
    const token = `${tokenType} ${accessToken}`;
    if (loggedIn) {
      config.headers['Authorization'] = token;
    }
    config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

//Add a response interceptor

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  function(error) {
    const originalRequest = error.config;

    if (
      error.response.status === 401 &&
      (originalRequest.url === `${apiURL}auth/login` ||
        originalRequest.url === `${apiURL}auth/refresh-token`)
    ) {
      // router.history.push('/auth/login');
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      const { refreshToken } = store.getState().auth;
      const { email } = store.getState().user;

      return axios
        .post('/auth/refresh-token', {
          email,
          refreshToken
        })
        .then((response) => {
          const { data: res } = response;
          if (res.code === 200) {
            store.dispatch(updateAuth({ ...res.token }));
            const { tokenType, accessToken } = res.token;
            axios.defaults.headers.common[
              'Authorization'
            ] = `${tokenType} ${accessToken}`;
            return axios(originalRequest);
          }
        });
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default axios;
```

Comment: thanks, will implement that. but in my case I still need the data in interceptor to be dynamic